# Is it safe to build one C++ static library with Android NDK r7 and other parts of an application with Android NDK r8e?

Tags: android, c++, c, abi

We hit an lot's of C++ crash in free/malloc with some random call stack.

I find one of the static is build with android ndk r7 and the other parts of whole app is build with Android NDK r8e.
After I update the library with ndk r8e build binary, it doesn't crash, but I cannot explain it.

I assume build static library with different NDK version and link them together is safe.

Can anybody confirm this and explain why it is safe or unsafe?

Comment: Why the close vote? The question is pretty clear.

Comment: Please leave comments if you down vote, and think I should improve the question.